# Read HTML Tags from DB without XSS Vulnerabilities

Tags: php, html, xss

I have a simple comments section with which I would like to be able to style each comment, saving the text and html tags in the database.

For the most part, I feel confident about the way I am inserting my comment data into my database. Of course, if you feel otherwise, I am not opposed to hearing your opinion.

```
if(isset($_POST["comment"])) {

    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $comment = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['comment']));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (`user_id`, `comment`, `parent_id`, `type`) 
        VALUES ('.$userid.', '$comment', '$parent_id', '$type')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Thanks for the comment!";
    } else {
        die("Error commenting" . $conn->error);
    }
}
```

However, if I go directly through MySQL and update a row to a simple javascript alert, it renders and I receive the alert on page load. Accordingly, I have a hole in my reading of the data.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    echo '<h1>'.$row['user_name'].'</h1>';
    echo '<p>'.$row['comment'].'</p>';
}
```

I know that I can make this safer through something like `strip_tags($row['comment'])`. However, if I do this, there cannot be any styling on the comments as `<p>` tags (and other tags for that matter) will be stripped. Accordingly, my question is this: how can I read the data in a way that prevents glaring XSS holes while allowing simple html styling (much like you see on these comments).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you can use a harmless `bbcode` in your commenting system for that matter, but i think you didn't understand `strip_tags()` well. `strip_tags()` has two arguments. first one is your string but second one is allowed tags (tags that can pass through `strip_tags()`) so it goes like this for example:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test texts.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">and other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);

# Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

and it outputs this:

```
<p>Test texts.</p> <a href="#fragment">and other text</a>
```

you can use `strip_tags()` documentation [here](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags()` has a second argument, which is a string of allowable tags.

In this case, all tags would be removed:

```
$comment = "<script>alert('Hello world');</script>This is <i>a comment</i>.";
$strippedComment = strip_tags($comment);
echo $comment;
```

This would result in: `alert('Hello world');This is a comment.`

However, with the second argument you can allow basic formatting tags, like so:

```
$comment = "<script>alert('Hello world');</script>This is <i>a comment</i>.";
$strippedComment = strip_tags($comment, "<i><u><b>");
echo $comment;
```

This would now result in: `alert('Hello world');This is <i>a comment</i>.`

http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the other answers are wrong: Using `strip_tags` is **not** secure.

The reason?

A user could simply enter code like this to bypass your sanitization:

```
<p onmouseover="alert('This could be evil XSS')">Test texts.</p> <a href="#fragment">and other text</a>
```

Passing this through `strip_tags` allowing `<p>` tags does not remove the code:

```
echo strip_tags("<p onmouseover=\"alert('This could be evil XSS')\">Test texts.</p> <a href=\"#fragment\">and other text</a>", "<p>");
```

as `p`'s attribute is still output:

```
<p onmouseover="alert('This could be evil XSS')">Test texts.</p> and other text
```

which will run:

[image: XSS is a running]

You should implement a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) on any pages where you output the user controlled text *in addition to* making the text safe for HTML output by using a sanitizer such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). This should be effective in preventing injected script commands from running.

The CSP allows you to effectively stop inline script from being executed by the browser. It is currently [supported by](http://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy) modern browsers such as Chrome and Firefox (although IE only currently has partial support).

This is done by a HTTP response header from your page.

e.g.

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

will stop inline JavaScript from being executed if a user managed to inject it into your page (it will be ignored with a warning), but will allow script tags referencing either your own server or `https://apis.google.com`. This can be customised to your needs as required. The HTML sanitizer is still needed for browsers that do not support CSP so you should still run all user supplied input through that first.